# Auto populate / screen scrape multipage webform

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Firstly apologies if this is a duplicate question, I have spent a while searching and can't find anything that looks to be the same.

I need to automate the completion of a multi page web form and then process the result from within an asp.net system.  The ideal solution would be to create a web service which takes in some data, then processes it through the website and returns a result - I can then use this in any app that requires this functionality.  The form that needs completing is quite complicated, and also includes some if / then / else logic when going through e.g:

1. Complete personal details
2. Enter postcode
3. If 1 result found goto 5
4. Display list of possible addresses, when one selected goto 5
5. If time at address < 3 years, display new address page

etc.

I have created a solution which launches an ActiveX browser control and controls the website as if a user were entering the data which works well however is subject to a limit on concurrent users (anything > 1 starts to cause issues, >2 is not allowed by windows default settings), is there a better way of doing this?  I've heard of Selenium although not used it, would this be a possible solution?

I have looked at using the WebClient class, and have used this in the poast for screen scraping systems however I don't know how I could chain these calls together to allow for the full workflow.

FYI - this work is all being undertaken with the full knowledge and consent of the site owner.  They have a queue of development tasks which building an internal API does not feature on so whilst they are happy for this type of solution to be implemented, will not be able to change anything their end.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is a .NET port of [Watir](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/) called [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) - it might be worth giving that a try if you haven't already.

Comment: I've not heard of it - looks to be a very similar solution to that I have already implemented but will check it out